# Can I use indexes for speeding up select queries over dateTime ranges in BaseX?

Tags: xquery, basex

I would like to ask about the way to speed up the select queries in a Basex database.
 I have for example the following xml in a database with many events(650000 approximately)

```
<EventList>
    <Event>
        <ID>317849</ID>
        <Type>Measurement</Type>
        <TimeStamp>2016-03-15T18:00:09.409</TimeStamp>
        <Space>BIOCAT</Space>
        <SourceID>BIOCAT.TE310A</SourceID>
        <Content>
            <Measurement>
                <value>920</value>
            </Measurement>
        </Content>
    </Event>
    <Event>
        <ID>317850</ID>
        <Type>Measurement</Type>
        <TimeStamp>2016-03-15T18:05:09.409</TimeStamp>
        <Space>BIOCAT</Space>
        <SourceID>BIOCAT.TE310A</SourceID>
        <Content>
            <Measurement>
                <value>920</value>
            </Measurement>
        </Content>
    </Event>
</EventList>
```

I am retrieving the events with the following code that selects with respect to the datetime of the Timestamp node

```
for $b in doc('mydb/my.xml')//EventList/Event
let $date_string as xs:string := xs:string($b/TimeStamp/data())
let $date as xs:dateTime := xs:dateTime($date_string)  
where $date ge xs:dateTime('"+startdate+"')
  and $date le xs:dateTime('"+enddate+"') 
  and $b/Type='"+EventType+"'
return $b
```

But it it is very slow it makes one minute to return 60 events.
There are many data in the BaseX database.
How can I speed up the request or my database?

Comment: If you'd properly indent the XML and add some reasonable line wraps to your XQuery code before posting, chances will heavily increase somebody will read your code. Furthermore, "many" is not a reasonable quantification, give the number of documents and nodes instead to provide some arguable numbers, same applies to "slow". Finally, why are you generally writing titles all lower-case, while getting it right in the question body?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BaseX currently does not have a range index for `xs:dateTime`, but you can use the text index for getting all events with a given event `Type` by moving the comparison into the XPath:

```
for $b in //EventList/Event[Type = 'Measurement']
let $date as xs:dateTime := xs:dateTime($b/TimeStamp)
where $date ge xs:dateTime('2016-03-15T18:00:00.000')
  and $date le xs:dateTime('2016-03-15T19:00:00.000')
return $b
```

In the *Info View* of the GUI you can see that the text index is applied:

> **Compiling:**
>
> - rewriting descendant-or-self step(s)
> - *applying text index for "Measurement"*
> - pre-evaluating "2016-03-15T18:00:00.000" cast as xs:dateTime
> - pre-evaluating "2016-03-15T19:00:00.000" cast as xs:dateTime
>
> **Optimized Query:**
>
> ```
> for $b_0 in db:text("mydb/my.xml", "Measurement")
>         /parent::*:Type/parent::*:Event[parent::*:EventList]
> let $date_1 as xs:dateTime := $b_0/TimeStamp cast as xs:dateTime?
> where (($date_1 ge "2016-03-15T18:00:00")
>   and ($date_1 le "2016-03-15T19:00:00"))
> return $b_0
> ```

Comment: I have tested the first query and it goes faster.
I didn't understand the explantation. why does it go faster?
Where is the info view of the GUI?
Sory I am a little bit confused.
Another question is if the optimized query will go faster than your first query and why.
Thank you in advance

Comment: I also get a 
"invalid database name" 
with the optimized query

Comment: Your original query scans over all `Event` nodes in the database and checks if they satisfy the three conditions. If an up-to-date *text index* exists this can be improved by (1) finding all text nodes in the database containing the string `"Measurement"` and then (2) going upwards in the document hierarchy to find the associated `Event`s. By reformulating the query in the way I did it, I helped the optimizer to find the second strategy. You can also use [db:text(...)](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Database_Module#db:text) directly if you want. The Info View can be toggled by pressing `Strg + I`.

Comment: so the optimized query will be faster than the first query that you have posted?
and could you please give me a way to surpass the error from the db:text("mydb/my.xml".....?
I get "invalid database name" error.
If I write 
db:text("mydb" 
I get 
"mydb has no text index"

Comment: No, Basex's query optimizer will rewrite the first query into the second one automatically. Do you read the XML data from a file each time or do you have it stored in a database? `db:text(...)` needs a database name as its first argument. But as I said, it should not be necessary to use it explicitly because the optimizer automatically rewrites my first query to use it.

Comment: The weird thing is that some times the request gets the response immediately and sometimes it has to wait 1.5 minute.
Is there  a possibility that the connections to the database do not close immediately?
session.close();
I use final BaseXClient session = new BaseXClient("localhost", 1984, "..","..");

Comment: That is unrelated to your original question, please create a new one for this.